# Cross-object Lookup Between Custom Objects

Tags: custom-object, lookup, lookup-filter

I am fairly new to Salesforce, and keep running into its many limitations.

I am just trying to make a Lookup field to find what category the item on my `Invoice Line` object has. The category field is on the `Inventory` object. These are all custom, managed objects with data from our ERP system.

I just want to be able to make reports based on invoices, organized by category. But I cannot get the category to show on the `Invoice Line` object, despite linking them together (I think) with their unique item ID, which is the same on both the `Invoice Line` object and the `Inventory` object.

I put the lookup filter as `Invoice Lines`->`Item UID` equals `Inventory`->`Item UID`

Comment: A lookup filter restricts the records that can be set on a lookup field. Think of it as a really fancy validation rule that also controls the lookup window. Does your `Invoice Line` object have a field on it that references an `Inventory` record? If so, did you set this lookup filter on the inventory lookup field?

Comment: I'm a bit confused -- are you trying to build a lookup filter that an end user would exploit in order to populate the Invoice Line's `Category__c` field?  Or, are you trying to traverse a multi-level foreign key relationship from Invoice Line to Inventory?  Perhaps if you put a picture of your schema it would be clearer to the Community

Comment: @crop1645 You are correct. I am trying to use the key `Item UID`, which is present on both objects, to pull fields from `Inventory` into `Invoice Lines`. This would take literally seconds in SQL, but they make me use salesforce.
Schema shot: http://cardboardsword.net/ss.jpg

Answer (score 2):

First check your datamodel and get it right. To just display a field from a relationship (parent) object in a page layout or report, you use a formula field. In this case the category field from the inventory object is displayed as a formula field in the Invoice Line object.